# Excel Counting IF Duplicated data based second column

Tags: excel, countif

I have the mantle of data of reprocess, that I want to analyze.

Case column are uniques values, attach to that person. Another person cannot take the case.

```
--------------------
Case    |  Name   
--------------------   
 512    |  John    
 921    |  John
 871    |  John
 871    |  John
 512    |  John
 881    |  Charles
 881    |  Charles
 881    |  Charles  
 244    |  Charles
 1002   |  Maria
 1841   |  Maria
 1002   |  Maria
 1891   |  Maria  
  .     |    .  
  .     |    . 
  .     |    .
```

I need a help with the logic itself to Analyze something Like

John |  6 Uniques cases | 20 Reprocess

--->  He had 6 Cases but In the flow they returned to him 20 times.

Hope I explain myself what I want.

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?

Comment: @TheTTGGuy With PivotTable, I can how many cases they have in total but how many reprocess they have.

Comment: even with summarizing the cases in the value area by count?

Comment: @pnuts Assume That I have a workflow where the cases have to past through, but in one stage the cases can have an error or not enough information, so that case have to return to the person who created the case to fix the problem.  So that cases create a reprocesses in the workflow, I want to determine who person create more reprocesses

Comment: @TheTTGGuy Got it.  I had to create the Pivot Table as Data Model and enabled Distinct Count. So I chose 
Person |  DistinctCount   |  NormalCount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your correctly, this will fit your needs nicely.  I would go through it, but it is one of the few Microsoft Help sheets that is actually well explained.

This is a formula approach.  You can also do this in a macro (VBA) as well, but I'm assuming you want to do this in Excel with a couple of formulas.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273#bmcount_the_number_of_unique_values_by_